# How i can see the actions in Zend framwork

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a project i created the database and i try to identificate with this  like

`http://localhost/xeo2-zend/public/authentification/connexion`
But i have this erreur

> Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 404

The project created with zend framwork 1.12
I'm tired with .htacces with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xeo2-zend/public/
```

And i'm tired to create the Alias but doesn't work also.

Help me please !

Comment: It would be best to setup Virtual host and access your page with url like `xeo2-zend.dev`. You can also try to access it like this http://localhost/xeo2-zend/public/index.php/authentification/connexion

Answer (score 0):

try this .htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$

RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

this is a universial .htaccess for the zend project.